# onItemClick ListView Listener not entering the first time

Tags: java, android, listview, onclick, listener

I have a problem in the onCreateView method, I have a fragment which has a button named: *variablesButton*, every time I click on it, it creates an *AlertDialog* in which I use the setMultiChoiceItems to display certain items. I'm trying to create a **Select all** in the first index to select all the items in the Dialog or to deselect them.

When I click the first time it does not work, but after clicking on it the second time it works (entering finally the onItemClick method). I already tried setFocusable to the listview, also FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS, but it won't enter the first time I click, how can I solve this?.

```
variablesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            mBuilder.setTitle("Sensors");


            mBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            mBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    listSensors.clear();
                    for (int a=0; a<checkedItems.length; a++) {
                        if (checkedItems[a])
                            listSensors.add(sensorNames[a]);
                    }
                }
            });

            mBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(sensorNames, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                    checkedItems[which] = isChecked;
                    Log.i("checked", String.valueOf(which));

                    final ListView listView = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
                    listView.setFocusable(false);
                    listView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                            boolean isChecked = listView.isItemChecked(pos);
                            Log.i("pos", String.valueOf(pos));
                            if (pos == 0) {
                                for (int i = 1; i < checkedItems.length; i++) { // we start with first element after "Select all" choice
                                    if (isChecked && !listView.isItemChecked(i) || !isChecked && listView.isItemChecked(i)) {
                                        listView.performItemClick(listView, i, 0);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            mBuilder.create();
            mBuilder.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, the first time the value of `pos` is logged? Can you see what's its value?

Comment: Hi @A.Wolf, no, I cannot see the value of pos the first time, but after second click I can see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()` is inside the `variablesButton.setOnClickListener` therefore AdapterView listener is set after variablesButton click listener fire once.

Move adapterView listener to the outside of this variable button clicked action. And set `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()` while initializing activity or initializing related content.